# ERROR: Cannot install ipykernel and jupyter-client because these package versions have conflicting dependencies

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pywin32

I come to you with a very specific error that I have been grappling with for a few hours now.
I am trying to run a jupyter notebook .ipynb file within VSCode running python 3.9.6. Of course I need the appropriate extensions, so I follow the VSCode prompts to install the recommended extensions. Installing jupyter NB seems to work, but ipykernel fails to install. It gives me the following request:

[image: Request]

So of course I copy that into CMD and let it run for a bit.

```
"c:/Program Files/Msys/mingw64/bin/python.exe" -m pip install ipykernel -U --user --force-reinstall
It fails to install: 
ERROR: Cannot install ipykernel and jupyter-client because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
...
To fix this you could try to:
loosen the range of package versions you've specified
remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
 
ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

[image: Image of full error.]

Repeating the ipykernal installation from VSCode and reading the notification prompts shows the same behavior.
I have tried clearing python cache in case that did anything, same problem.

I have tried reading the conflict resolution page as recommended, but I don't understand how to access the requirements.txt file or setup.py, I just don't know what I am doing here and don't want to end up spinning my wheels for a few hours.

I have tried installing pywin32 separately as it seems to want an updated version of it.

```
pip install pywin32 
"pip install pywin32
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32" 
A [different stack overflow thread ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981120/python-pip-cannot-find-pywin32-on-windows) said to try pypiwin32
pip install pypiwin32
Which gives the following error: 
File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vhqvsbur\pypiwin32_d3dd60d8846243c3be165c2c90439a4b\setup.py", line 121
print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version
                ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Building pywin32", pywin32_version)?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVez4.png)
Which googling shows may be a python2 vs python3 syntax change or something, but that's a rabbit hole I don't know how to go down.
```

The other people in the robotics club didn't have this problem, I am just cursed XD

Comment: Hey, did your issue get resolved?